# list slider as background color and anchor on it

Tags: html, css

I implemented a slider with tree changes colors using `fade` animation I created, and added to each link `a` link with different URL.

actual result: do not open correct link based on color(item) slider
expected result: open link with based on slider's item

https://codepen.io/palaniichukdmytro/pen/MWWBQrb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are stacking all elements on top of each other. So the last element (which happens to be the link to google) is always on top - therefore this one will always receive the click event.

Setting the opacity to 0 does not change that. Although you can't see the element, it is still on top and clickable.

To solve your issue, you can either change the positions of your elements using `z-index`, which would put the correct element on top

or you could set it to `display: none` when at zero opacity, which would actually stop the element from being displayed and interactable with

or you could set `pointer-events: none`, which would make the element still "visible" but ignore any interactions. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: I updated with z-index, but not sure it helped or I missed some keyframe settings

Comment: Put them into the fade keyframes. You don't need the fadeLink animation at all. https://codepen.io/Fitzi/pen/QWWBmNp